# Notation to use to define two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, permutations, notation

Consider the $K\times 1$ vector of integers $V\equiv (1,2,...,K)$.
Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the collection of all possible $K\times 1$ vectors that I can obtain by rearranging in various orders the $K$ elements of $V$ without repetitions. How do I formally define it?
For instance, if $K=3$, then I would write
$$
\mathcal{A}\equiv \{(i,j,h): (i,j,h)\in \{1,2,3\}^3, i\neq j\neq h\}
$$
I don't know how to write $\mathcal{A}$ for a generic $K$.

Now, consider a generic $K\times 1$ vector $V$ listing some real numbers, ordered from smallest to largest with possible repetitions. Let $B$ denote the $(K-1)\times 1$ vector listing the relational operator between consecutive numbers in $V$. For example, if $K=3$ and $V=(2,4,4)$, then $B\equiv (<,=)$. Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the collection of all possible $B$. How do I formally define it? For instance, if $K=3$, then I would write
$$
\mathcal{B}\equiv \{(<,=), (<,<), (=,<), (=,=)\}
$$
I don't know how to write $\mathcal{B}$ for a generic $K$.

Comment: Do you mean all permutations of $(1,2,\cdots K)$ ?

Comment: Yes, $\mathcal{A}$ is the set of all possible permutations. Thanks. How about $\mathcal{B}$?

Comment: I think they are called permutations with repetitions. They are also $K$-tuples.